# How to reduce Mysql execution Time?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using Mysql 5.5.16. I've a query where i combine 3 queries using union opeartor... Each query contains more than 10000 records.

My Query looks like...

```
$search_qry1 = " (SELECT PC_name as name FROM profile_category_tbl WHERE PC_status=1 and PC_parentid!=0  and (";
$search_qry2 = " (SELECT PROFKEY_name as name FROM profile_keywords_tbl WHERE PROFKEY_status=1 and (";
$search_qry3 = " (SELECT COM_name as name FROM ".$C."_company_profile_tbl WHERE COM_status=1 and (";
$order_by = "ORDER BY";
$word_length = explode(" ", $my_data);

for($i=0; $i <= count($word_length) - 1; $i++) {
    $dt = $word_length[$i];
    if ($dt) {
        if ($i == 0) {
            $or="";
        }
        else {
            $or="OR";
        }

        $search_qry1 .= " $or regex_replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]','',remove_specialCharacter(PC_name)) LIKE '%$dt%' ";
        $search_qry2 .= " $or regex_replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]','',remove_specialCharacter(PROFKEY_name)) LIKE '%$dt%' ";
        $search_qry3 .= " $or regex_replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9\-]','',remove_specialCharacter(COM_name)) LIKE '%$dt%' ";
        $order_by .= " IF(name LIKE '%$dt%',1,0) ";
    }
    if ($i == count($word_length) - 1) {
        $search_qry1 .= ")";
        $search_qry2 .= ")";
        $search_qry3 .= ")";
    }
    if ($i != count($word_length) - 1) {
        $order_by .= "+ "; 
    }
}
$search_qry1 .= " GROUP BY PC_name  )";
$search_qry2 .= " GROUP BY PROFKEY_name  )";
$search_qry3 .= " GROUP BY COM_name  )";

$search_qry = "select name from ( $search_qry1 UNION ALL $search_qry2 UNION ALL $search_qry3 )a $order_by desc LIMIT 0,25";
```

It works perfectly... but it takes the time to execute it - more than 4 secs... for each search.... how possible to reduce its execution time?.... If anyone know an idea about this please let me know....

Actually I run this query for auto-complete search. If type "`Rest`" in search box, then

```
The Output Should be, 

Family Restaurants
Everest Park
Fast Food Restaurants
Everest Park Residency
Fish Restaurant
Everest Power Solution
Fish Restaurants
```

Thanks in Advance,
Jeni

Comment: Are any of the columns you're searching through indexed in any way?

Comment: Please post final SQL query, since it's all about it, not PHP.

Comment: Also add the output from explain on the different SQL statements.

Comment: You say: `My query looks like...`, but you post php code. Make your mind!

Comment: I love the `$or="OR";` bit xD

Comment: Your code looks like... a huge mess. Indent it!

Comment: If you want us to help optimize a query, **you need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly.  If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well.

Comment: Yeah Andrius Naruševičius, Kindly go through the last line... its query... i write a php code for this only.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `regex_replace` and `like "%foobar%"`,
that actually slows down your query significat, since mySql has to do a fulltext search and the regex operation on every single row. Maybe it's faster if you do these operations after you fetched your results, using php instead of mysql.

Comment: Thanks...Actually I run this query for auto-complete search. When I remove regex_replace it'll works little bit faster.but fulltext search is not working here. for example: if type "Rest" in search box, then the output should be... Family Restaurants, Everest Park, Fast Food Restaurants, Everest Park Residency, Fish Restaurant, Everest Power Solution, Fish Restaurants

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you're doing a full scan of each table to check the like '%$dt%' condition. No matter which indices you have on the table, none of them will be used.

But if you post the final SQL sentence and what are you trying to do maybe we could help.

Comment: Thanks...Actually I run this query for auto-complete search. if type "Rest" in search box, then the output should be... Family Restaurants, Everest Park, Fast Food Restaurants, Everest Park Residency, Fish Restaurant, Everest Power Solution, Fish Restaurants,